# c++ checking to see if data is equal or not

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am writing a program and have to check if the character entered by the user is equal to one of the characters in an array. If it is not equal to any it should display "Invalid....". It is not working for me can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong. I am getting invalid character every time.

I have a char array data[5]; that stores 5 letters

```
 cout<<"Enter one character to delete: ";
 cin>>del;


 cout<<del;
 for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
      if(del!=data[x])
        {
         cout<<"Invalid, character not entered.\n";
         break;
         }

    }
```

Comment: If `del` does not equal `data[0]`, the `break` statement will take you out of the for loop (without trying the other values of x).

Comment: I suggest using `std::string` and `std::string::find` (and `std::string::erase` to delete one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int x=0;x<5;x++)
{
  if(del==data[x])
    {
     cout<<"Character found at " << x << endl;
     break;
     }

} if(x==5) cout<<"Character not found" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your character array is a C-style null-terminated string, then you can use strchr:

```
#include <cstring>
//...
if (strchr(data, del)) {
    // character found
}
else {
    // character not found
}
```